# How can I modify an existing column's data type?

Tags: mysql, types, sqldatatypes

One of the columns in a somewhat large table (~10,000 records) is of the data type DECIMAL(10,0). I'm using MySQL.

I'd like the values to be displayed to 2 decimal places, so I need to alter this to DECIMAL(10,2), without screwing up the table's existing records. How could this be done?

Comment: This will depend on the RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc) you are using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Which DBMS are you using ? you can try like this for MySQL :

```
alter table tblName modify columnName newDataType;
```